# Is nesting a h2 tag inside another header with h1 tag semantically wrong?

Tags: html

Is nesting a h2 tag inside another header h1 tag semantically wrong?

```
 <h1 class="fixed">
    <h2 class="absolute">
        Absolute Div
    </h2>
</h1>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: whats the harm in knowing a thing :)

Comment: [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Can't argue with that!

Comment: Yes it's wrong, both semantically and the fact you can't nest headings - `Heading cannot be a child of another heading.`- from the w3c validator.

Comment: Never understood why people comment correct answers

Comment: @Artyom seems to me they r not hungry for SO reputation but instead in solving the issue ;)

Comment: @iBlue Putting answers as comments is semantically wrong!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

“Semantically wrong” is largely a matter of opinion (“semantics” means “relating to meaning”, but what would be the meaning here?), but the construct isn’t even *syntactically* (formally) correct. According to all HTML specifications and drafts, an `h1` element must not contain an `h2` element.

As regards to markup for a “subheading”, or a secondary part of a heading, there have been heavy debates on it, especially as regards to the proposed `hgroup` element (which would let you use `h1` followed by `h2` as if it were a single heading). The practical approach has been, and still is, to use markup like

```
<h1 class="fixed">
Primary heading text<br>
<small class="absolute">
Secondary heading text
</small>
</h1>
```

I have preserved your class names here, but they suggest that perhaps you should not be using heading elements at all. The `h1` element is supposed to be the overall heading for the *page*, and an `h2` element is supposed to be a heading at the next lower level, for a top-level section of the page.

Comment: IDK if this is a new term, but "eyebrow" has been thrown around a lot lately, and refers to what you mentioned, with a subheading of sorts enclosed in a heading. Searching for that yields nothing specific, but I'm wondering now in 2020+ what would be considered the best practice here, in regards to what is referenced by the new hot-word, 'eyebrow'.

Answer (score 1):

It would be yes, as the `<h>` tags are meant for headers and should not be nested.

So you are putting a header within a header.  Easier to just separate as normal:

```
<h1 class="fixed">
    </h1>
<h2 class="absolute">
    </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 standard quote that says you can't**

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements 4.3.6 The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements says that those elements can only have phrasing content ("inliny things" like bold or italics or links):

> Content model: Phrasing content.

But h1-6 themselves are not phrasing content: they are flow content, the other major category of "blocky things" like parapgraphs:

> Categories: Flow content. Heading content. Palpable content.

So you can't nest them.

Answer (score -8):

Yes absolutely you can nest H tags and it is good idea to do so for best page SEO ranking.
The reason you want to do this is to pack a page with correct heading tags but allow the CSS numerical H setting you desire for display formatting.

You have a few options:

1. the one you have shown is correct: `<h1><h2> Your heading</h2></h1>`
   W3C validation will have a fit with this so I recommend option 2 that fakes W3C validation and browsers out.
2. Use a Themco X-Theme with the `[custom_headline]` tag.
   Here is how this works:

   ```
   [custom_headline type="center" level="h1" looks_like="h2"]Your Heading[/custom_headline]
   ```