# Can I nest these tags?

Tags: html

I hear that using a `<p>` tag inside an `<h1>` tag is wrong, and that using a `<p>` tag inside another `<p>` tag is also wrong. Is that the case?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>There was <p>before us a long <h3>piece </h3> of level road by the </p>riverside.</h1>

<p>John said to me, <b>"Now, <p>Beauty</p>, do your best"</b> and so I did</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)." -- [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

Comment: [Is it valid to have paragraph elements inside of a heading tag in HTML5 (P inside H1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid)

Comment: [Is nesting a h2 tag inside another header with h1 tag semantically wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363465/is-nesting-a-h2-tag-inside-another-header-with-h1-tag-semantically-wrong)

Comment: nesting p tag is wrong? above example p tag code is right or wrong? if wrong then why?

Comment: My first comment addresses nested `<p>` tags. Specifications indicate that `<p>` tags are not intended to be nested.

Answer (score 3):

According to HTML specifications, some "flow" elements should not contain other "flow" elements. The [`<p>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) and [`<h1-6>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) elements can be used where ["flow content"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#flow-content-2) is expected, but are expected to contain only ["phrasing content"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content-2). As such, they should not contain each other.

You might ask yourself: "Why do I want to nest `<p>` tags? What am I trying to accomplish?" There's probably a more effective method of achieving that goal. If you are using those tags to change the look or styling of the text, I recommend building structurally appropriate markup and then styling it as desired with CSS.

For example, if you're trying to group two paragraphs together, consider wrapping them in a `<div>` rather than nesting two `<p>`:

> Authors wishing to conveniently style such "logical" paragraphs consisting of multiple "structural" paragraphs can use the div element instead of the p element. -- [the p element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-p-element)

---

HTML specifications indicate that:

- `<p>` tags should not be nested.
  `<p>` tags are considered "flow elements" and can only contain "phrasing content".
  In other words, a paragraph contains text, but wouldn't contain another paragraph.
- `<h1>` tags should not contain `<p>` tags.
  The same rationale applies here. Both of these "flow elements" can only contain "phrasing content" and should not contain each other. Consider using a different child element, like a `<span>`. Also see [this answer about "p inside h1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779519/is-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid#answer-19779520).
- `<h1>` tags should not contain other heading tags like `<h3>`.
  In my opinion, a heading is either "level one" *or* "level three". Nesting them doesn't make sense. See [this answer about "h2 in h1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363465/is-nesting-a-h2-tag-inside-another-header-with-h1-tag-semantically-wrong).

---

For reference:

> #### 4.4.1 The p element
>
> **Categories:**
> Flow content.
> Palpable content.
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
> Where flow content is expected.
>
> **Content model:**
> Phrasing content.

> #### 4.3.6 The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements
>
> **Categories:**
> Flow content.
> Heading content.
> Palpable content.
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
> As a child of an hgroup element.
> Where flow content is expected.
>
> **Content model:**
> Phrasing content.

-- [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/)